# & not allowed in string type in sails model

Tags: angularjs-scope, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

```
//Food.js

module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    foodName: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    imgUrl: {
      type: 'string'
      //required: true
    }

  }

};
```

While saving the food item If I am giving "Roasted Fennel & Apple + Curried Red Lentils" as food name, then in MongoDB it is saving like "Roasted Fennel".
It's not allowing any chars after "&".

Can anyone plz help me how to save special chars like "&","+" etc.

Comment: Did you try to escape it like \&

Comment: While entering the food name in text field I tried.It didn't work.

Comment: If you remove & and + all your field is correctly saved ?

Comment: Yes @jaumard It's saving if +, & are removed.

Comment: You can try to set back slash on your controller and finally have Roasted Fennel \& Apple \+ Curried Red Lentils if you put it on input text they are change direct http request

Comment: In sails controller also I am not getting what exactly given in the view by using req.param("foodName") .
May be it's due to angularJs scope variable as I am using angular controller to get the data from scope variable and again passing to Sails controller by calling rest api.

Comment: so the problem it's not mongoDB, I think you have a problem between your view and controller please show us your code

Comment: Yes @Jaumard. You are right. Let me look into my angular controller.